# Pad an array to be a certain size

Tags: ruby, arrays

There's probably a more efficient and more Ruby-ish way to do this:

```
# Pad array to size n by adding x's. Don't do anything if n <= a.length.
def padleft(a, n, x)
  return a if n <= a.length
  return padleft([x] + a, n, x)
end
```

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Edited due to my misunderstanding of the question. Pervious version of my answer padded from the right side, but the question was asking to do it from the left side. I corrected it accordingly. This is due to naming convention. `ljust`, `rjust` are builtin methods for `String`, and I extended that convention to `Array`, but that corresponds to `padright` and `padleft`, respectively, in the terminology of the question.

**Destructive methods**

```
def padleft!(a, n, x)
  a.insert(0, *Array.new([0, n-a.length].max, x))
end
def padright!(a, n, x)
  a.fill(x, a.length...n)
end
```

It would be more natural to have it defined on `Array` class:

```
class Array
  def rjust!(n, x); insert(0, *Array.new([0, n-length].max, x)) end
  def ljust!(n, x); fill(x, length...n) end
end
```

**Non-destructive methods**

```
def padleft(a, n, x)
  Array.new([0, n-a.length].max, x)+a
end
def padright(a, n, x)
  a.dup.fill(x, a.length...n)
end
```

or

```
class Array
  def rjust(n, x); Array.new([0, n-length].max, x)+self end
  def ljust(n, x); dup.fill(x, length...n) end
end
```

Comment: NB: `n` is the largest desired index, not the desired array length.

Answer (score 5):

FWIW:

```
def rpad(item, padding, num)
  Array(item).fill padding, Array(item).size, num
end
# rpad "initialize value(s)", 0, 3
# => ["initialize value(s)", 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `10` for the length to pad to, and `'x'` to be what you're padding to, this pads right:

```
>> asdf = %w[0 1 2 3 ] #=> ["0", "1", "2", "3"]
>> asdf += (asdf.size < 10) ? ['x'] * (10 - asdf.size) : [] #=> ["0", "1", "2", "3", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x"]
```

or

```
>> asdf = (asdf.size < 10) ? ['x'] * (10 - asdf.size) + asdf : asdf #=> ["x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "0", "1", "2", "3"]
```

to padleft

If it makes sense to you to monkey-patch Array:

```
class Array
  def pad_right(s, char=nil)
    self + [char] * (s - size) if (size < s)
  end

  def pad_left(s, char=nil)
    (size < s) ? [char] * (s - size) + self : self
  end
end

%w[1 2 3].pad_right(5, 'x') # => ["1", "2", "3", "x", "x"]
%w[1 2 3].pad_left(5, 'x') # => ["x", "x", "1", "2", "3"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the * operator to repeat a list.

```
# Pad array to size n by adding x's. Don't do anything if n <= a.length.
def padleft(a, n, x)
  return a if n <= a.length
  return [x] * (n - a.length) + a
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another fun one-liner to do it:

**(non-destructive)**

```
def padleft(a, n, x)
  a.dup.reverse.fill(x, a.length..n-1).reverse
end
```

**(destructive)**

```
def padleft(a, n, x)
  a.reverse.fill(x, a.length..n-1).reverse
end
```

Comment: Just curious, why the downvotes? Is this no longer a correct solution?

Comment: Sorry I intended to write a synopsis while downvoting, but some other thing came up. Reversing 2x should never be a correct solution when dealing with oft-used string functions. Code like this is the root of most slowdowns in open-source software. 

When there is code like this in a core string library, someone will rewrite it using a single reallocation and a loop to set the padding characters and brag about it on his/her blog.

Comment: It may be inefficient, but this is attractive code nonetheless. When writing Ruby we often value poetry above practicality. As long as it's not done in a massive loop, I think we are good.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps more *Rubyish* ;)

```
# Pad array to size n by adding x's. Don't do anything if n <= a.length.
def padleft(a, n, x)
  (n - a.size).times.inject(a) do |array, i|
    array << x
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Rails and want the padding on the right:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6].in_groups_of(4)
=> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, nil, nil]]
```

This doesn't come anywhere near answering the question but it's what I ended up needing after visiting this page.  Hope it helps someone.